# How do we know if an ImageView is updated in Android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a form, where I have a imageview and other two text fields. This imageview will be updated with the pic a user chooses(either from gallery or by taking a pic). I will be saving this image in internal storage and other two text fields and saved image path in SQLite DB.

User has option of not choosing any image. In that case I should not save any image, coz I simply be wasting storage. For that how do I distinguish when a user chooses or not to upload any image?

Comment: What about you implement something here : `User has option of not choosing any image`

Comment: You can have a boolean variable which tracks this state? You can modify this local variable based on the user action and eventually use this to decide if you need to persist the image path.

Comment: @JonZarate If the user did not choose any image, I should not save the preview image as it is available already there in my Resources folder.

Comment: @SandeepCH Don't save the Image, save a `Boolean mUserPickedImage = false` and save it somewhere.

Comment: @Bhargav I thought of that but I do not want to keep extra column in the DB just for this. The image path is a string, and I insert a particular string to filter out those data which don't have image with it. But the problem I am facing here is I do not know when to save the image and when not to.

Comment: @JonZarate Thanks. I now understand what you're saying. I will do that

Comment: @Bhargav Thank you for your help. Will implement what you explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
int NEW_PIC=1;
int NO_CHANGE=0;
```

initialise

```
img_camera.setTag(AppConfig.NO_CHANGE);
```

when Changed set

```
img_camera.setTag(AppConfig.NEW_PIC_ADDED);


    if ((int) iv_userImage.getTag() == NEW_PIC_ADDED) {
    //New Image Added
    }
    else{

//Not New
}
```